# Stripe with Webtask

Tags: stripe-payments, webtask

I've been working for days on implementing Stripe Checkout into my static site.  My static site is generated by React.  There is a tutorial for setting up Stripe Checkout using React, however I also need to move the backend function to webtask.

Here is the tutorial.  https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-express-stripe-payment/#express-stripe-backend

Any idea on how to port this over to webtask?

Comment: You need rework this question a bit. For example, what did you try? I assume you created an account, added a webtask, and attempted to recreate what is documented. And I assume something failed there. Can you share that?

Answer (score 1):

It should be pretty much the same thing, except that the author in this tutorial is:

1. **Exporting an express server**. To use that with webtask you're going to need to explicitly define the [programming model](https://webtask.io/docs/model) with the argument `--meta wt-compiler=webtask-tools/express` (or you can use [webtask-tools](https://github.com/auth0/webtask-tools)).
2. **Splitting the code into multiple files**. Luckily `wt-cli` provides a bundler so it's just a matter of providing the `--bundle` argument.

So the final command line becomes:

```
$ wt create index.js --bundle --meta wt-compiler=webtask-tools/express
```